# Argumento de uma função é outra função

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber como colocar como argumento de uma função uma outra função.

Por exemplo, digamos que quero resolver uma integral por um determinado método numérico de aproximação de integral. E quero criar uma função que faça isso, na qual os argumentos da função são:

```
Integral = function(a,b, fx)
```

Em que `a` e `b` são os intervalos de integração e `fx` é a função que quero integrar.

---

Ainda não esta dando certo. Veja:

```
trapezio.integracao <- function(a, b, fn){ fn(x) }
 {
   x = seq(a, b, by = 0.005)
   n = length(x)

   integral = 0.5*sum((x[2:n] - x[1:(n-1)]) * (f(x[2:n]) + f(x[1:(n-1)]) ) )

   return(integral)
}

fx <- function(x){x^2}

trapezio.integracao(0,1,fx)
```

Comment: Se entendi bem o que você está querendo fazer, você está cometendo dois erros aí:

1 - `trapezio.integracao <- function(a, b, fn){ fn(x) }` isso define uma função que aplica a função `fn` a um objeto `x` que não existe dentro do escopo daquela função

2 - o trecho abaixo disso é o que provavelmente você quer usar dentro da função e mesmo assim, vc não está fazendo uso do argumento `fn`. Veja minha resposta atualizada pra entender melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta passar a função como argumento, por exemplo:

```
funcaoSoma <- function(a,b){a + b}
funcaoAritmetica <- function(a, b, fn){ fn(a,b) }
```

Quando você executar `funcaoAritmetica(2,3,funcaoSoma)`, R irá executar a função passada pelo argumento `fn` e te retornar o valor 5.

EDIT:

A função que você postou não funciona porque não faz uso correto da função como argumento, o correto seria:

```
trapezio.integracao <- function(a, b, fn)
 {
   x = seq(a, b, by = 0.005)
   n = length(x)

   //Aqui você irá usar a função passada como argumento,
   // pelo nome de 'fn' (o nome que está indicado na definição da função) e não 'f'

  //No seu exemplo, ficaria assim:
  integral = 0.5*sum((x[2:n] - x[1:(n-1)]) * (fn(x[2:n]) + fn(x[1:(n-1)]) ) )


   return(integral)
}

fx <- function(x){x^2}
```

Desta forma, quando você executar, terá o seguinte resultado:

```
> trapezio.integracao(0,1,fx)
[1] 0.3333375
```

Comment: Ainda não esta dando certo, veja o meu programa abaixo. :/

Comment: Muito obrigada! Agora entendi o erros que cometi.